# Variable set in forEach loop getting wrong type

Tags: typescript, control-flow, type-narrowing

When setting a variable from inside a `forEach` callback function, that variable's type doesn't seem to come out right. A simple example:

```
let foo: (string | null) = null;

[1,2,3].forEach((i) => {
  foo = "bar";
});

if(foo == null) {
    throw new Error("not found")
}

# Typescript complains that `length` is not a property of type `never`
console.log(foo.length)
```

[Typescript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/FAGwpgLgBAZg9nKBeKA7AriEBuYwDaAjADQBMxAzALoB08ATgKICGAxgBYAUnAlgJTIAfFADewKLATIoAIgBGzejNwBfPrmA8YneIiQoMWAWIkSI7enADuaMDcb1L9TjNRxo8dKgAmMvsBU8VjhUAGc4cBoQOABzHQQosFQY8z4gA)

Right after the `forEach` I'd expect the type of `foo` to be `string | null`, but it's actually just `null`.  By the `console.log` line I'd expect it to be just `string`, but it's actually `never` (since we've eliminated `null` as a possibility with the `Error` throwing.

Importantly, the above code (minus the `: (string | null)` bit) works perfectly fine in plain JavaScript - this is purely a case of me and the TypeScript compiler not communicating properly somehow.

So anyway:

1. I'd love it if someone could explain why this is so that I can understand Typescript better and
2. How do I get around this?  I can just slap a `foo = foo as string` just before the console.log, but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the trade-offs of the control flow analysis.

By annotating the type `string | null` you tell the compiler the variable, obviously, expects a value of either type. You then make an assignment to `null`, which lets the compiler narrow the type to `null`.

You expect that TypeScript accounts for the assignment inside the callback and forgoes the narrowing, but it does not. This is a trade-off the team made when deciding whether mutations happening in functions passed as parameters to higher-order functions should leak to the outer scope.

See [this source repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) discussion on the matter.

Answer (score -2):

That's not a TypeScript behavior, rather a EcmaScript one's. The `forEach` defines a scope for the variable, so what happens inside, it remains inside.

Have a look here, for instance: https://alligator.io/js/foreach-vs-for-loops/

Comment: exactly, just to complment your answer.
Because the scope of forEach the compiler is assuming that foo is equal null and there is no length property in null object. null.length it's impossible.

Comment: But in ecmascript you can easily modify variables outside the scope defined by the forEach function.  This works completely fine:
```
let x = 0;
['a','b','c'].forEach(() => {x = x + 1});
console.log(x); // prints 3
```
And, as mentioned in the question, the example code I gave *runs* fine - it just doesn't type check, which would imply that it's a typescript problem, not an ecmascript one.

Comment: you're right: I've mistook the problem. I'll give a point to the other answer.