# TS infers "never" type because it can't grok assignment in forEach loop

Tags: typescript

The error reads `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.`

I understand enough about TypeScript to have thought that [Control Flow Analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) would have me covered in this scenario. When I declare:

```
let quantityRange: QuantityLevels | false = false;
```

And, while iterating through one of the function parameters, a `QuantityLevels` typed variable *may* be assigned:

```
priceList.quantityLevels.forEach((ql) => {
  if (ql.min <= quantity && ql.max >= quantity) {
    quantityRange = ql;
  }
});
```

When we eliminate the possibility of `false` being the value assigned to `quantityRange` for the remainder of the function by throwing an error in that case. However, TypeScript infers that the variable `quantityRange` could not have been assigned anything other than `false`, and is typed as `never` for the remainder of the function.

When I try to use properties of `quantityRange`, I'm rebuffed:

```
const priceByProduct = priceList.prices[product.id][quantityRange.id].price;
// error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

What's going on here? If I make an assignment of

```
quantityRange = priceList.quantityLevels[0];
```

(`priceList.quantityLevels` being typed as `Array<QuantityLevels>`), then all is well. This leaves me thinking that I must have an incomplete model of understanding when it comes to the way TypeScript deals with function/block-scoped variables. I've read through [what I think](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#variable-capturing-quirks) are the [relevant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#block-scoping) [sections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#block-scoped-variable-capturing) of the TypeScript handbook and have come up empty-handed (or perhaps empty-headed).

The code won't pass a `build` action, but in the development and test environments, it's working as expected.

[The code below also rendered in TypeScript playground, along with errors.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCcYVQCgG9EA3AQxzLCgEkARAGkQEcQrYoBPJgBxzwAyMAM5REAXwBciAOLpsuVNjg9hASkSEAUIkQAbdCzbUYXAEpU00gIrGOnAahKo9wxAB9EwMq9SIAvF4%20wqgA3Fo6iHyKQqIAdKzspg5OLsJxwHBYAKJkEAAW%20PjMehr%20AHyakbowwIjFenEAtjBIADyBiSZciABkvSyNTWQAHojlnXbJGtq6c0ZJ5pZ%20nXrh8%20KR4mrhkQD0ewvdnBZgaAFR-KixUAlTXI7OrgDaAAwAuuuIB4gAeogAWSobD0ek4iDIwmEMGQYFayEQUHyInqAHdkQVECj0WQoAByNz5Mg8HioOFnLFIJF%20MgAIzgzi8WX0cBUGn2h10wwA1qg3AAVADKiHAABNUFhRFRRXEIjU6vgAIRdeynNAzaqI-JYOCoxBgVB67JYHVYfAAAwAcnAjvZEFhlkyxUysIgACSEFXJcSIOB1D3kSjUejiOLmnZbOWICAIUSXOCikDQC7RQQiW5QChoKDpYCtUX4TX4KBlSq3QMwdi5-NFEil0hxGCigL%20QIV9j0NQMSIRyK1eqKvgJpMlqrzJE6vUGo0mrIWgDCcBAembYDgYjzYGbZHjieTWBcuNQzagNvb1HdhHPtDoofDX02kRjYDjqdQACFOMo92JAm%20bnEb7CM8Q4-o2orvM8XpLGcqDge8gFXF8z6vlcn4AGoUJWF5-lcAFASBOpgU2kHQScyzwc8170J8UYHlAIBYEg%20BvhhWHsB4nisV%20REjhG4i7FwpKILYiwpE8biBLMWKitIog4GcXwtGA0hgCATS0hKSmjKp6maVg4SPq0UASt4eCIJaZBNMe2THGOMlyVACnIF8YBWagjnOaEiBaAJETGaZeR%20N%20I6IKgIwmVubiWdZoq2Xa0nXsI0gAIImmQnBtDFNnHOUhkREJwV4emFzSZmWDZsliBpQ6mUhdAeWRGRjxpKl6WZaJxwta4jW6EB0jSbohHDtA9CefC7wDZqQ3NakehjYg8kTVN8zzG%20ukaVp01zFR7HBnQ41nJN%20p6Vtq0SJqmy6JsflaIVsjyFcyiqKVkTUQdi1OfCXxkRt%20lfP%206bSAoaaiIZ4RAA)

```
function getPrice({ variantID, quantity, priceList }: GetPriceProps) {
  let quantityRange: QuantityLevels | false = false;

  priceList.quantityLevels.forEach((ql) => {
    if (ql.min <= quantity && ql.max >= quantity) {
      quantityRange = ql;
    }
  });

  // quantityRange = priceList.quantityLevels[0];
  // ^ Manually assigning this (which is what's happening in the above for loop) 
  //   makes TS understand.

  if (!quantityRange) {
    throw new Error(`No quantity range found for ${quantity} of ${variantID}.`);
  }

  const product = priceList.targets.find(
    (t) => t.variants.find((v) => v.id === variantID),
  );

  if (!product) {
    throw new Error(`Could not find a product related to variant ${variantID}.`);
  }

  const priceByProduct = priceList.prices[product.id][quantityRange.id].price;
  const priceByVariant = priceList.prices[product.id][quantityRange.id][variantID];

  return (priceByVariant || priceByProduct);
};

type QuantityLevels = {
  id: string;
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

interface NamedEntity {
  id: string;
  name: string; 
};

interface Product extends NamedEntity {
  variants: Array<NamedEntity>;
}

type PriceList = {
  targets: Array<Product>;
  quantityLevels: Array<QuantityLevels>;
  prices: {
    [productID: string]: {
      [quantityLevelID: string]: {
        price: number;
        [variantID: string]: number;
      }
    }
  }
};

type GetPriceProps = {
  variantID: string;
  quantity: number;
  priceList: PriceList;
};
```

Comment: Seems related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084305/variable-set-in-foreach-loop-getting-wrong-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) when instantiating the variable instead of an annotation. This will prevent TS from inferring that it is only `false` thereafter in the rest of the scope, even in code blocks which present difficulties regarding [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

```ts
let quantityRange = false as QuantityLevels | false;
```

Your modified code in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCcYVQCgG9EA3AQxzLCgEkARAGkQEcQrYoBPJgBxzwAyMAM5REAXwBciAOLpsuVNjg9hASkSEAUIkQAbdCzbUYXAEpU0iALyJgZPcNSIywxAEVjHTgNQlUjogAPnYOTgDcWjqIfIpCogB0rOymPn4BwgnAcFgAomQQABb4+Mx6GtYAfJrRujDAiKV6CQC2MEgAPLbJJlyIAGT9LM0tZAAeiJXdXqka2roLRinmls7depGL4tHiapHRAPQHS72cFmBWtrGCIlBJM1y+-o4A2gAMALqbiEeIAHqIACyVDYej0nBcwmEMGQYHayEQUEKIkaAHdkUVECj0WQoAByNyFMg8HioOEXLFIJHOMgAIzg-jsOX0cBUGkOx10owA1qg3AAVADKiHAABNUFhRFRRQkonUGvgAIQ9bznNBzWqIwpYOCoxBgVB63JYHVYfAAAwAcnATt5EFhVkyxUysIgACSEFWpcSIOAND3kSjUejiBLmvY7OWICAIUQxHWikDQGzxuK3BJQChoKCZYDtUX4TX4KAVap3QMwdi5-MlEil0gJGCimzWWwV9j0NQMaIR6L1RqKvhwRPQDWLJE6vUGo0mnIWgDCcBAembYDgYjzYGbZHjw6TYiwAVxqGbUBt7eo7sIF9odFD4e+22iMbAceuqAAQpxlCOxFd+Kg8R3O+wgvEOv6NqKHwvF6KwXKgkEfAk77fC+b4AV+ABqFCVpe-5pokIFgQm+6ITBDxnKsZE3vQXxRoeUAgFgSD4O+WE4ewwQhGx34kaOkTiPsXCkh4FFPBkKbzFiorSKIOAXN8bRgNIYAgC0tISop4wqWpGlYAJUTtFAEr2HgiCWmQLQnrkpw1HUMmIHJ8LfGAlmoLJUDycg4SIFogmGdQJkFM4P77ogqBjMZW5uBZVmijZdpSTewjSAAgiaZCcB0sXWaclQGVowkhQBQGSdEmZYNmKWIOlDpZaF0D5dEsFpM81W1ZlHSeMsrUZE1uggdIUm6MRe7QPQHleR8Q2aiNLXiXoE2OZ58LTXZiwLO+OnqZps0LC8NF0JNq3bXp3xbJq2y6Ns-mFZwIlyJgAHKKoZW6Idx0Kc1FGnbtA0lbc0gKDcogCZEQA)

Comment: Spot on. I like this because lets me be quite plain with TypeScript about what's going on. I like the annotation syntax, as it makes for easier reading, IMO, but this serves a different purpose. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CameronHurd Note that you can also use an [assertion function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625025/438273) in place of your error-throwing conditional to narrow the type.

Answer (score 5):

Using `forEach` and the argument closure makes TypeScript less accurate with its control flow analysis. This [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) contains some more information.

If you replace

```
priceList.quantityLevels.forEach((ql) => {
  if (ql.min <= quantity && ql.max >= quantity) {
    quantityRange = ql;
  }
});
```

with a for-of loop:

```
for (const ql of priceList.quantityLevels) {
  if (ql.min <= quantity && ql.max >= quantity) {
    quantityRange = ql;
  }
}
```

The type of `quantityRange` is inferred correctly.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCcYVQCgG9EA3AQxzLCgEkARAGkQEcQrYoBPJgBxzwAyMAM5REAXwBciAOLpsuVNjg9hASkSEAUIkQAbdCzbUYXAEpU00gIrGOnAahKo9wxAB9EwMq9SIAvF4%20wqgA3Fo6XnBYiPgQCKIseohwwIh8ikKiAHSs7KYOTi7qmpG6MGn4zHrZALYwSAA8gXkmXIgAZB1JdWQAHogAfC12BRraupNG%20eaWfi164VPikSuRFbEAhK32FmBo42WIUAAWWHAA7ohgqFcAoljnWPgABgBycNNtnIhYc1HgAAmURiABJCDsCuIUmlweRKNR6OJsi81EsJBFdPEwIk%20HBASBoAF0vxUFkoNkoBQ0FBhNlgA1AfgjvgoBp-INjtl4TB2HSGWAmfgSOzOSRsjBgf5paQKLzEXQ1AxImjMYgNvhNniCdBDlNTucrjd7o9oq8AMJwEB6YFgOBiAXAsgk-GEsRYFxkKCoYFQT489iIOFy9hIlGq3RrLEJMQZPAAIU4yh1YkCcbJIgp6eEAG1tW6JYCALo5yGzfaoQtF7Lp9HY3GkxMANRD1GJ6fJNdJufz0CrpdG5bQ-YDCqL4UiHqgICwSHw6ebrbE7k8C6T5xTqvEE64PD8thmhWcrmJE3VgOkohw%203R9TA0jAIFqACNUFhb-0H0-X%20%20tGsGt6WDeHgiBvGQtQ%20nc3ylOUF6IFeDTIOiYDgagl5QNeSGIH%20E4AW%20wF%20MmbqIKgfTeoKbhgRBgJQfYMGygitLSAAgo8ZCcI0VGQd8gzhGsu6EaS5KnpEVJYDSwgsWxHFEdAvGRGWR7FFJfwcQe3yOMewjybo2bSGeuh5hubr0OhmFFvpRyGYpmkuKZ8EYYhFn0VMumkl%20L5vuirmIDmo60HQZlOR5P7eZMKzLKsOERAJsjyKSyiqCJuj%20fZCE3gpg6cCFXmRB2mbSAogiZnx4RAA)